# bibtex URL not complete

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I have a BibTeX entry that looks like this:

```
@url{ClaimsReservingManual,
    Author = {Institute and Faculty of Actuaries},
    Date-Added = {2013-10-02 08:18:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-10-02 08:39:02 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {02.10.2013},
    Publisher = {Institute and Faculty of Actuaries},
    Title = {Claims Reserving Manual},
    Url = {http://www.actuaries.org.uk/research-and-resources/pages/claims-reserving-manual/},
    Year = {1997},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.actuaries.org.uk/research-and-resources/pages/claims-reserving-manual/}}
```

I use this in a LaTeX document. It displays the URL in my bibliography but when I click it it takes me to `http://www.actuaries.org.uk/research-and-resources/pages/claims-reserving-`instead of the proper URL.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide more information as to *how* you compiled the document. E.g., did you compile it straight to pdf, or first to dvi (followed, possibly, by further steps to create a pdf file)? How is the URL string rendered in the pdf file? Specifically, is there currently a line break after "reserving-"? Do you use BibTeX (and possibly some citation management package such as `natbib`) or biblatex/biber to create the bibliography? Incidentally, you should probably place a second set of curly braces around the contents of the `author` field to inform bibtex that the author is "corporate".

Comment: I use BibTeX (with biber). I compile straight to PDF. The URL breaks after reserving- in my document.

Comment: You can't use BibTeX (the program) and biber at the same time. Please provide a minmal working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it. I added

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
```

to the preamble and now clicking the link takes me to the correct webpage. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution. Be sure to encase the author field in a second set of curly braces so that biblatex/biber won't generate an entry such as "Institute, of Actuaries, F." or an authoryear-style citation of the form "Institute and Actuaries".